# Program crashes while using gets C programm

Tags: c

I want to get many string inputs with "gets" ("Enter" should be considered as input in my program).
but my program always crushes after the first "gets" input
This is a simple example that could probably explain what I am talking about:

```
int main()
{
    char* str;
    char* str1;
    puts("Enter the first String");
    gets(str);
    fflush(stdin);
    puts(str);
    puts("Enter the second String");
    gets(str1);
    puts(str1);
    return 0;
}
```

the program crushes just before getting the second string input

Comment: You must allocate some buffer to read the strings in before reading strings. Also you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11. Another note is that `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin), so you shouldn't use that.

Comment: `char* str` -> `char str[100]`, read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book